# open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)

Tags: nginx, permissions, arch-linux, nextcloud

Currently, I've set up a nextcloud server with `nginx` and I enabled it with `sudo systemctl enable nginx.service`. When I'm rebooting, than I'm getting an error message which complains about a proxy server and if I take a look into `sudo systemctl status nginx.service`, than I'm getting this:

```
nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-11-14 12:20:55 CET; 16min ago

Nov 14 12:20:55 TORNAX-ARCH systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Nov 14 12:20:55 TORNAX-ARCH nginx[473]: 2020/11/14 12:20:55 [warn] 473#473: could not build optimal types_hash, you should increase either types_hash_max_size: 1024 or types_hash_bucket_si>
Nov 14 12:20:55 TORNAX-ARCH nginx[473]: 2020/11/14 12:20:55 [emerg] 473#473: bind() to 192.168.178.35:443 failed (99: Unknown error)
Nov 14 12:20:55 TORNAX-ARCH systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 14 12:20:55 TORNAX-ARCH systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 14 12:20:55 TORNAX-ARCH systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

If I run `nginx -t` than I'm getting this:

```
2020/11/14 12:37:40 [warn] 68391#68391: could not build optimal types_hash, you should increase either types_hash_max_size: 1024 or types_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring types_hash_bucket_size
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
2020/11/14 12:37:40 [emerg] 68391#68391: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

When I'm looking for a solution about this `open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)` error, than I'm only getting solutions for docker + nginx like these posts:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57427162/nginx-emerg-open-var-run-nginx-pid-failed-13-permission-denied
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64393237/nginx-emerg-open-run-nginx-pid-failed-13-permission-denied
- https://dockerquestions.com/2020/10/16/nginx-emerg-open-run-nginx-pid-failed-13-permission-denied/
- https://github.com/Wonderfall/dockerfiles/issues/40

It works after restarting manually the service with `sudo systemctl restart nginx.service` but I'm still getting the `open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)` when I'm running `nginx -t`.

What am I doing wrong or what can I do in order to solve this problem?

Comment: Run `nginx -t` as root. This is a red herring.

Comment: If I run it with root, everything looks fine (except the `types_hash_max_size` error).

Comment: Of course it does. That's because it is completely irrelevant to the problem, as I already said. The actual problem is `Nov 14 12:20:55 TORNAX-ARCH nginx[473]: 2020/11/14 12:20:55 [emerg] 473#473: bind() to 192.168.178.35:443 failed (99: Unknown error)`

Comment: I think that I'll create a new question for that since my main question has been answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be a bug. "This behavior is a known bug, caused by a race condition between nginx and systemd. Systemd is expecting the PID file to be populated before nginx had the time to create it."  https://www.cloudinsidr.com/content/heres-fix-nginx-error-failed-read-pid-file-linux/

### EDIT

In any case, if the website is down again, here are the steps to fix it:

#### Step-By-Step guide

1. Create a directory named nginx.service.d in /etc/systemd/system/:

```bash
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d
```

2. Add the following to `/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/override.conf`:

```
[Service]
ExecStartPost=/bin/sleep 0.1
```

3. Reload systemd manager configuration:

```bash
systemctl daemon-reload
```

4. Restart NGINX:

```bash
systemctl restart nginx
```

#### Copy + Paste commands above

```bash
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d
echo "[Service]\nExecStartPost=/bin/sleep 0.1\n" > /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/override.conf
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart nginx
```

### Link to bug report

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nginx/+bug/1581864

Comment: Wohooo! Thank you! It works!!!!

Comment: That link is bad.  What needs to be done?  I have this as well.  @TornaxO7

Comment: I don't exactly know how I did that but I just know that you need to let the service wait a bit. I guess something like `ExecStart=sleep 1 && /usr/bin/nginx -g 'pid /run/nginx.pid; error_log stderr;'` should work

Answer (score 11):

`sudo nginx -t`

This comment should have been an answer imo.

`Run nginx -t as root. This is a red herring. – Michael Hampton Nov 15 at 0:27`

Comment: Well yes, it's a part of the answer, but I still've got a problem when I'm rebooting my system as Michael Hampton pointed out.